# Check if a string from a column in a dataframe exists in a column in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

[image: **DF1**]

and a second one as shown below

[image: **DF2**]

I would like to combine them to one dataframe like this one

[image]

Comment: Is the string you are looking for always in brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'select from [mary_flowers]'], [2, 'select from [esther_pots]'], [3, 'select from [somthing]']], columns=['item_id', 'Column_x'])
df['view_name'] = df['Column_x'].str.extract(r'\[(\w*)\]', expand=True)[0]
df.loc[~df['view_name'].isin(list(df2['view_name'])), 'view_name'] = np.nan
df
```

Output:

```
   item_id    Column_x                    view_name
0   1        select from [mary_flowers]   mary_flowers 
1   2        select from [esther_pots]    esther_pots     
2   3        select from [somthing]       NaN
```

Explaination: This extracts the `table_name` from the [], and than checks if it's in you second `df`, changing it to `np.nan` if not.

EDIT:
If you can have more than one table name in 'Column_x' use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'select from [mary_flowers] join [tom_trucks]'], [2, 'select from [esther_pots]'], [3, 'select from [somthing]']], columns=['item_id', 'Column_x'])
names = ['mary_flowers', 'esther_pots', 'tom_trucks']
df['view_name'] = df['Column_x'].str.findall(r'\[(\w*)\]')
df['view_name'] = df['view_name'].map(lambda views: [v for v in views if v in list(df2['view_name'])])
df
```

Output:

```
  item_id   Column_x                                     view_name
0       1   select from [mary_flowers] join [tom_trucks] [mary_flowers, tom_trucks]
1       2   select from [esther_pots]                    [esther_pots]
2       3   select from [somthing]                       []
```

Comment: I think it would be better to do `df = df.merge(df2, on='view_name', how='inner')` to match OP's desired output.

Comment: @JulienRoullé That will remove the lines in `df`if they don't exists in `df2`, which I don't think is what he wanted. I added the 3rd line (that doesn't exist in the question) to show what happens if the name doesn't exist in the second `df`.

Comment: Thanks @Aryerez. It works if there is only one value in [value_to_extract] in the query. If I have joined many views, it only picks the first one and moves on.

What can I do to extract the two of them from a query like this

"SELECT 
* 
FROM [mary_flowers]
LEFT JOIN [tom_trucks] ON 
LEFT JOIN [mary_dolls] ON"

Comment: @JeffersonSankara I've edited it. Next time, if you have more complixity than the simplest case, please add reference to that in the original question, so you will get a more accurate answer in the first time.